# Directory '.' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found. when using anaconda

Tags: python, pip, installation, anaconda

I'm using anaconda navigator, and had some issues with installing python2 but I eventually got it figured out. However, now every program in anaconda when using python3 looks for packages when importing in anaconda's py36 lib folder, instead of anaconda's lib folder. However, pip is installing into the anaconda lib folder.

I want to change the pip install to the py36 lib folder. However, when I run

```
pip install --root = "C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/site-packages"
```

I get the error

```
 Directory 'C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/site-packages' is not installable. File 'setup.py' not found.
```

What I don't understand is that the current install location doesn't have a setup.py file in it either.

Does anyone know a solution? Thanks